# Unmarshal json request body to a structure which has a struct member of custom interface type

Tags: json, go, encoding, interface

Lets consider the following code

```
type A struct {
    Column1 string `json:"column1"`
    Entity CustomInterface `json:"entity"`
}

type CustomInterface interface {
    GetType() string
}

type Entity1 struct {
    ColumnX string `json:"columnx"`
    ColumnY string `json:"columny"`
}

type Entity2 struct {
    ColumnP string `json:"columnp"`
    ColumnQ string `json:"columnq"`
}

func (*e Entity1) GetType() string {
    return "ENTITY1"
}

func (*e Entity2) GetType() string {
    return "ENTITY2"
}
```

Now if I am trying to bind an instance of `A` type as follows

```
var bodyJSON A
ShouldBindWith(&bodyJson, binding.JSON)
```

I am getting the following error

```
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field A.entity of type package.CustomInterface
```

Am I doing anything very silly here?

PS: I just started exploring go. Apologies if this question is very noob level.

Comment: try this `var bodyJSON *A`

Comment: If you don't provide a concrete type, the package can't know what to unmarshal into.

Comment: @JimB Yes I agree. Otherwise there is no way for the runtime to figure out which type to unmarshal to. The way I can make it work is read it as an `interface{}` and type cast it to appropriate type depending on a certain condition. Kindly let me know if there is any better approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The `json.Unmarshal` function by itself does not let you unmarshal into interface types except for the empty interfaces (`interface{}`) that don't have any methods:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores [one of these](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) in the interface value:
>
> - `bool`, for JSON booleans
> - `float64`, for JSON numbers
> - `string`, for JSON strings
> - `[]interface{}`, for JSON arrays
> - `map[string]interface{}`, for JSON objects
> - `nil` for JSON null

However, in some simple cases the following scheme can work.

```
type CustomerEntity struct {
    CustomerName string `json:"customer_name"`
    Address      string `json:"customer_address"`
}

type EmployeeEntity struct {
    EmployeeName string `json:"employee_name"`
    ID           int    `json:"employee_id"`
}
```

If we know that an entity is either an employee or a customer, then we can define an `Entity` that embeds each:

```
type Entity struct {
    CustomerEntity
    EmployeeEntity
}
```

We can give it methods to check whether it's a customer or an employee:

```
func (s Entity) IsCustomer() bool {
    return s.CustomerEntity != CustomerEntity{}
}
func (s Entity) IsEmployee() bool {
    return s.EmployeeEntity != EmployeeEntity{}
}
```

Really, these are just checking that at least one field is set.

Then we unmarshal the following JSON:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "employee_name": "Bob",
        "employee_id": 77
    }
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Example struct {
    Entity Entity `json:"entity"`
}

type Entity struct {
    CustomerEntity
    EmployeeEntity
}

func (s Entity) IsCustomer() bool {
    return s.CustomerEntity != CustomerEntity{}
}
func (s Entity) IsEmployee() bool {
    return s.EmployeeEntity != EmployeeEntity{}
}

type CustomerEntity struct {
    CustomerName    string `json:"customer_name"`
    CustomerAddress string `json:"customer_address"`
}

type EmployeeEntity struct {
    EmployeeName string `json:"employee_name"`
    EmployeeID   int    `json:"employee_id"`
}

func main() {
    var example Example
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"entity":{"employee_name":"Bob", "employee_id":77}}`), &example); err != nil {
        panic("won't fail")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", example)
    if example.Entity.IsCustomer() {
        fmt.Printf("customer %s lives at %d\n", example.Entity.CustomerName, example.Entity.CustomerAddress)
    }
    if example.Entity.IsEmployee() {
        fmt.Printf("employee %s has id %d\n", example.Entity.EmployeeName, example.Entity.EmployeeID)
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
main.Example{Entity:main.Entity{CustomerEntity:main.CustomerEntity{CustomerName:"", CustomerAddress:""}, EmployeeEntity:main.EmployeeEntity{EmployeeName:"Bob", EmployeeID:77}}}
employee Bob has id 77
```

as we might expect.

There are a few caveats. First, this won't work if there's overlap in either the JSON or the Go field names for the entity types. Second, nothing stops you from (accidentally) initializing some fields in both the customer and employee types and causing it to return true for both `IsCustomer` and `IsEmployee`.

If your JSON data has a `"type"` field, then you could use it to decide what is held instead:

```
type Entity struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
    CustomerEntity
    EmployeeEntity
}
```

although this has the same drawbacks as the other solution mentioned above.